# How to escape variables in C#?

Tags: c#, string, variables, escaping

I want to know if what wrong is with
this peace of code? I mean how to escape
to variables from strings (in C#)? (if I had correctly understood what escaping is.)

```
int i;
string s;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
s="\u00A"+i;
Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

(Actually I want the program to write
a sereies of unicode chatacters to make a uncode table for example 00A9=® and 00A5=¥.
Or in general I want to use a variable after backslash)

To make it simple:

```
string a,b;
a="t";
b="n";
Console.WriteLine("Hi\{0}All\{1}",a,b);
```

Which I want to type a tab and insert a new line (I know it's possible to write \n and \t in WriteLine directly but I assume we want to get the special chracter from user)
Thanks in advance. ☺

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What research have you tried? This question is arguably a rudimentary question best served by reading a _Welcome to c#_ book or tutorial.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to indicate just what you expect `x` to be, and what that has to do with escaping.

Comment: Searched  but found nothing❌

Comment: @Ali is "Unicode table" your actual goal? It is quite possible you completely misunderstanding what "escape" means for strings because only way your last line would be useful if you generating C# (or Java/C/C++/JavaScript) code that later will be compiled... String consisting of `'\\'` and `'t'` (2 characters, notice that to represent \ in C# you need to escape it) is very different from `'\t` - single character with code 9.

Comment: yes I probably misunderstood it. BTW I was imagining a program like this: 'Console.WriteLine("\nHello");
string s = Console.ReadLine();
string sp;
switch (s)
{
case "t":{ sp="\t"; break;}
case "e":{ sp="\n"; break;}
case "u":
{
Console.Write("Type your unicode number: ");
string st = Console.ReadLine();
sp=char.ConvertFromUtf32(int.Parse(st,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
break;
}
default :{ sp="Error"; break;}
}
Console.Write(sp);
Console.Write("You!"); ' Nevermind.Not many people use console these days I think(I was learning C# and this question popped).Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int i;
string x;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
x= @"\u00A" + i; //if you want the backslash
// without @ it's x= "\\u00A"+i; //so the backslash is escaped
Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

**Edit**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(
         char
         .ConvertFromUtf32(
             int.Parse("00A"+ i, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)));
}
```

The only thing you can do about the other problem:

```
string a,b;
a="\t";
b="\n";
Console.WriteLine("Hi{0}All{1}",a,b);
```

Comment: No need to say thanks in here =) but you are welcome.

Comment: `for(char c = 0xa9;c < 0xb5; c++)` would be so much simpler... but not what OP asked... (@Ali - would be nice to explain why you can't use simple `for`)

Comment: Actually I can but my purpose was to use a variable after a \ like ' "\MyVariable" ' which we have got it from user for example 'MyVariable=n;' and it seems it's not possible for C# which compile the code first (is it?) (however it's also possible to get from user like this 'MyVariable="\n";' but it wouldn't be actually using a variable after backslash anymore)

Comment: @Ali no it isn't possible... how would a compiler (good piece of software as it is but not THAT intelligent) distinguish between the cases ... escape sequences are to be seen as one character i.e. "/n" is one linebreak and "\t" is one tab stop. theres no way around it and that is totally ok. you got so many functions that makes life with strings easy so there will always be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode escape sequence requires 4 digits:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  var x="\u000A"+i; // notice 3 zeros
  Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Notes

- usually you'd use `"\n"` for new line (or even [`Environemnt.NewLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx)) like `Console.Write("\n" + i);`
- adding integer (or any other value) to string causes automatic call to `.ToString` so you can add any object to string. Often it is better to use `String.Format("\n {0}", i);` instead of `+` to provide more flexible/readable formatting (adding many strings - have better methods - search).
- if you are looking for writing out characters with code to particular integer value (like 32 is space) you should cast it to `char`: `x="\u000A"+(char)i` - also you should pick printable range (like 32-42).

Comment: Oh I think it's been misunderstood. I want unicode chars not ascii. for example 00A9=® and 00A5=¥